# how do I add a package to a devops artifact? (NonAuthoritativeInformation your package was pushed)

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-artifacts

Access to my normal package feed is temporarily failing and I need to organise an alternative.

I have the relevant files locally
[image: files]

It would be wonderful if I could simply upload them into the feed.
But I see no upload option to do this.

When I click Connect to feed I see instructions

```
nuget.exe push -Source "feedname" -ApiKey az <packagePath>
```

So I tried at the dos command line
but got an error

```
The specified source 'feedname' is invalid. Provide a valid source.
```

The feed does actually exist.

[Update]

After following Turbot's advice, and after figuring out my user name was my email, I got a message NonAuthoritiveInvormation "Your package was pushed" but I do not see it yet.

Checking [this issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4403)

[Update]

My commands look like this

```
nuget.exe sources add -Name "MyFeedName" -Source "https://dev.azure.com/MyTeam/MyApp/_packaging?_a=feed&feed=MyFeedName" -username "kirsteng@mydomain.com.au" -password "mypat"


nuget push -Source "MyFeedName"  -ApiKey az C:\Users\kirst\.nuget\packages\mypackage\1.0.173\mypackage.1.0.173.nupkg
```

I put the commands into a .bat file
When I re-run it I also see that

```
The name specified has already been added to the list of available package sources. 
Provide a unique name.
```

I guess that makes sense.

I also see

```
NonAuthoritiveInformation 
https://dev.azure.com/MyTeam/MyApp/_packaging?_a=feed&feed=MyFeedName 
Your Package was pushed
```

Yet it was not.

I also tried enclosing the package name in double quotes.

I see from typing nuget ? that

```
 push              Pushes a package to the server and publishes it.
                   NuGet's default configuration is obtained by loading %AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.config, then loading any n
                   uget.config or .nuget\nuget.config starting from root of drive and ending in current directory.
```

I wonder if that is relevant somehow.

Nuget.exe is Version: 5.9.1.11

Here are  [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-push)

[Update]

I found that the add command was writing to

C:\Users\kirst\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\Nuget.Config

I edited that to remove the feed and re-ran my bat file.
Then I was able to get it to work.

The other thing I had wrong was the url itself. It should have been like

```
https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/myapp/_packaging/myfeedname/nuget/v3/index.json
```

Comment: not sure you are using the source url correctly, but if you (assume using Azure DevOps Service) navigate your portal menu Azure Artifact -> Select your feed -> click Connect to feed, choose Nuget.exe -> will give you instructions , look on the value of the url and that need to added in Nuget.Config or using command like I shared.

Comment: I have it working now with your help. The instructions at Connect to Feed were pretty confusing. Asking me to install Azure Artifacts credential provider and add a nuget.config file to my project. Well I dont want to have a project! and I am using an PAT so I dont need to install the credential provider.

Comment: glad it works for you ! the instructions is for newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to be precise in Azure DevOps using Nuget
you need to supply userid and PAT to in nuget.config or in command.

```
nuget sources add -Name <SourceName> -Source <SourceURL> -username <UserName> -password <Pat>
nuget push -Source <SourceName> -ApiKey az <PackagePath exp:(.\Get-Hello.1.0.0.nupkg)>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am making a mistake in the push command.  What do you mean by exp:(. ?

Comment: exp is example :) , you can supply the value between < >

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar issue when doing this Artifacts feed work recently. My learnings are as follows

1. Documentation by MS is not that great (in one place) in this area. So it was mostly trial and error for me.
2. PAT which can be used to publish packages should have this scope
   [image]
3. How to get the feed url?

   - In ADO web UI, go to Artifacts and select your feed in the drop down
   - Press "Connect to feed"
   - If you are using nuget as feed then click on Nuget.exe option.
   - Right side, it will show you your url along with steps to add it in nuget.config.
4. But the above is fine in case you want to pull packages. What about pushing packages say through command line?
   Using these 2 commands we can do that

   nuget sources add -Name "Your feed name" -Source "Feed url" -username
    -password "PAT with Packaging scope"

   nuget push -Source "Your feed name" -ApiKey "some string, I am not sure whether it is used in pushing packages" <PackagePath exp:(.\Get-
   Hello.1.0.0.nupkg)>

Comment: The trap is that nuget looks up a config file and what is in it matters. I think that was why I was going around in circles.